# Historical VIX term structure data

Tags: volatility, vix, term-structure

I see that there is a CBOE page for collecting individual moments of term structure data, however, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to access historical data in bulk.  Here's the CBOE page:

http://www.cboe.com/trading-tools/strategy-planning-tools/term-structure-data

I saw this page, which seems to indicate that bulk data was previously available, but it looks like the full term structure is no longer available through the above page.

https://www.macroption.com/vix-term-structure-historical-data/

Comment: Not sure about CBOE. But if you have access to option metrics, then you have call options data on the SPX, and you can easily compute the term structure.

Comment: I don't have that at the moment.  Is it readily available?

Comment: It does seem that the CBOE has removed the bulk download feature and now only offers the data or 1 user selected date.